# A2C Loss Function Explosion

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, actor-critic

I am training OpenAI's implementation of the A2C algorithm found [here.](https://github.com/openai/baselines/tree/master/baselines/a2c)  Based on the mean episode reward graph below we can see it is in fact learning the policy function up until roughly 2000 updates:

[image: mean episode reward]

However, after roughly 1000 updates we see the overall loss explode as well as the value function loss:

**Overall Loss:**

[image: overall loss]

**Value Function Loss:**

[image: value function loss]

Also note the explosion of mean value across states:

[image: mean value across states]

Is the sudden "explosion" of overall loss a normal characteristic of A2C?  Most of this significant jump seems to be attributed to the value function loss.

Note: Based on domain knowledge I know our value function is relatively hard to approximate and thus why we chose the policy gradient method A2C.

Comment: the loss from RL are notoriously noisy and unstable, so as long as the policy is actually improving in terms of actual reward I wouldn't worry too much

Comment: Thanks @shimao.  I guess I'm concerned because I was expecting training to last for millions of episodes, rather I am seeing convergence after 1k updates (1 minute wall time).

Comment: but it doesn't look like it's converged yet?

Comment: @shimao sorry I should have included more episodes in the graphs.  The overall loss diverges after ~4.5k updates and onward.

Answer (score 2):

It might be connected to the entropy regularisation. If you're using A2C from [baselines](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/9cb7ece3387c4cb680fd831f38400b356bd599a6/baselines/a2c/a2c.py#L37) implementation, it has `entropy*ent_coeff` term for the loss.

Entropy flattens your distribution making `std` grow. Track the standard deviation and if it's growing, this might be an issue. Or just try to set `ent_coeff` to zero.